# When does 明日辺り start and finish?

Tags: meaning, nuances, time

Is 明日辺り exactly the same as 明日?

If not, let's say I just got told "`Please do <something> 明日辺り`", then:

- From what time today does it start to become acceptable to do it?
- Approximately when will it start to be considered as later than expected?

Comment: I'm a Japanese, and now I'm also curious what the answer is. :) It isn't the same as 明日 for sure. I think it can sometimes mean something like "Please do <something>, say,  tomorrow?", too.

Answer (score 2):

It means kind of "tomorrow or the next day", accurately "tomorrow or another day if you can't afford tomorrow".

Answer (score 1):

I think '明日あたり' is more widely used but same meaning.

明日 and 明日あたり are different.

明日 == tomorrow

明日あたり == tomorrow but with some tolerance. It means a day after tomorrow is possible option. But not today. Because most people know today's own schedule.

25日あたり == In general, 24, 25 or 26 if today is not 24.